# How do I force multicol to run horizontally first instead of vertically?

Tags: multicol, alignment

Using a standard `enumerate` environment within `multicols` results in this:
[image: Current result]

How do I end up with:

```
a b c
d e
```

instead of:

```
a c e
b d
```

I'd like the items to always run left-to-right and then up-to-down rather than up-to-down and then left-to-right.

Comment: don't use multicol as you do not want the text flow to be by column, just use an inline enumeration eg from `enumitem package.

Comment: Maybe you (Alby) would find the [tasks](https://ctan.org/pkg/tasks) package useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:  either the `shortenumerate` environment (from the `shortlst` package), with a small patch to let you choose the number of columns of alignment (key `nc`), or the `tasks` package, which unfortunately doesn't line exactly with the upper enumeration, so I had to add a hack.

Here is a demo of both ways:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{counter-format=(tsk[a])}
\usepackage{mathtools, bigstrut}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\usepackage{shortlst,setspace,xkeyval, tasks}%
    \makeatletter
    \newcounter{ncol}
    \define@key{lex}{nc}[3]{\setcounter{ncol}{#1}}%% 3 columns by default
    \newenvironment{tabenumerate}[1][]{%
    \setkeys{lex}{nc,#1}
    \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\mbox{(m)}}
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%[1][3]
    \setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/\value{ncol}-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\ensuremath{\arabic{enumi}.}}
    \begin{shortenumerate}}%
    {\end{shortenumerate}
     }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{tabenumerate}[nc = 3]
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
  s & = \frac{d}{t} \\[1ex] s & = \frac{\SI{10}{\m}}{\SI{10}{\s}} \\ s & = \SI{10}{\m\per\s}
\end{aligned}$
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
  s & = \frac{d}{t} \\[1ex] s & = \frac{\SI{1000}{\m}}{\SI{50}{\s}} \\ s & = \SI{20}{\m\per\s} \\
\end{aligned}$
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
  s & = \frac{d}{t} \\[1ex] s & = \frac{\SI{630}{\m}}{\SI{31}{\s}} \\ s & = \SI{30}{\m\per\s}
\end{aligned}$
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
  s & = \frac{d\strut}{t} \\[1ex] s & = \frac{\SI{200}{\m}}{\SI{25}{\s}} \\ s & = \SI{8}{\m\per\s}
\end{aligned}$
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
  s & = \frac{d}{t} \\[1ex] s & = \frac{\SI{156}{\m}}{\SI{9}{\s}} \\ s & = \SI{10}{\m\per\s}
\end{aligned}$
\end{tabenumerate}
\bigskip
\item \leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep + \partopsep}
%
\begin{tasks}[label-offset=0.75em](3)
\task $\begin{aligned}[t]
  s & = \frac{d}{t} \\[1ex] s & = \frac{\SI{10}{\m}}{\SI{10}{\s}} \\[0.6ex] s & = \SI{10}{\m\per\s}
\end{aligned}$
\task $\begin{aligned}[t]
  s & = \frac{d}{t} \\[1ex] s & = \frac{\SI{1000}{\m}}{\SI{50}{\s}} \\[0.6ex] s & = \SI{20}{\m\per\s} \\
\end{aligned}$
\task $\begin{aligned}[t]
  s & = \frac{d}{t} \\[1ex] s & = \frac{\SI{630}{\m}}{\SI{31}{\s}} \\[0.6ex] s & = \SI{30}{\m\per\s}
\end{aligned}$
\task $\begin{aligned}[t]
  s & = \frac{d}{t} \\[1ex] s & = \frac{\SI{200}{\m}}{\SI{25}{\s}} \\[0.6ex] s & = \SI{8}{\m\per\s}
\end{aligned}$
\task $\begin{aligned}[t]
  s & = \frac{d}{t} \\[1ex] s & = \frac{\SI{156}{\m}}{\SI{9}{\s}} \\[0.6ex] s & = \SI{10}{\m\per\s}
\end{aligned}$
\end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]